# How to create lifecycle aware components with Hilt?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

Let's say, I have a MediaRecorder class that I will be using in a different fragment which looks this way:

```
class Recorder @Inject constructor(
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    private val mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder
) : LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    fun startRecording() {
        mediaRecorder.prepare()
        mediaRecorder.start()
    }

    fun stopRecording() {
        mediaRecorder.stop()
        mediaRecorder.release()
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    fun onPauseEvent() {
        mediaRecorder.pause()
    }
}
```

I want to inject here the lifecycle of the fragment/activity that I will be using here.

How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure about injecting lifecycle . How about  you use `addObserver(recorder)` in the class where you are creating it . and remove lifecycleConstructor argument . Its better this way i think .

Answer (score 2):

Try out via activity context

```
class MyClass @Inject constructor(@ActivityContext context: Context) : LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        val activity = context as AppCompatActivity
        activity.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    private fun onStart() {

    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    private fun onStop() {

    }
}
```

If this class is shared between fragments then add `@ActivityScoped` annotation